# iDrac intermittent packet loss

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, drac

We have some new `Dell R230` and it has a weird issue.

Some of the iDrac when pinging has replies but as soon as enter the creds and login then ICMP becomes `Destination unreachable` and so iDrac isn't reachable.

The ICMP will recover after few hours and the iDrac. And then again attempting to login causes ICMP to return `destination unreachable` and then iDrac will be down for a couple of hours.

What can be the reason? I'm thinking about upgrading firmware if available but I can't do it remotely atm.

This is iDrac 8. Only one or two iDrac's are stable. Rest of them have the same issue as reported above.

Comment: Why is this an issue? The purpose of the IDRAC isn't to respond to ICMP traffic, it's to give you OOB access to the server. Is the iDRAC unavailable when this happens? Can you get to the iDRAC login page?

Comment: oh that's what I meant. iDrac is unavailable. It becomes unavailable when we try to login. ICMP is showing that something is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue.

We had to adjust iDrac switch port speed and enable portfast as well.

Here are the links that helped solve the issue:

https://www.dell.com/community/Systems-Management-General/iDRAC6-connectivity-issue/m-p/3876652/highlight/true#M15223

https://support.oneidentity.com/kb/204398/why-is-the-link-interrupted-message-displayed-at-the-bottom-of-the-virtual-console-